# Convert DDMMYY to DD-MM-YY in SSIS Derived Column

Tags: ssis, substring, ssis-2012, derived-column, ssis-2016

I am facing issue while placing "-" in a varchar datatype.
. Need is after last two digits we need to put "-" and then again after two digits and so on.

> Input String is- 21220 Output String- 2-12-20

Or,

> Input String- 311220 Output String- 31-12-20

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a script component for string manipulation because it's much easier to do and it's more readable.

1) Add a script component as a transformation

2) Under input columns, check your date column (I called this myDate in the example below)

3) Under Inputs and Outputs, under Output 0, add a column for the new date, called formattedDate below

4) In the script, modify the Input0_ProcessInputRow method.  Before parsing the string, make sure it's not null.  Then pad it with a "0" on the left to insure that we always have a length of 6.  Parse, the date elements and set the value for the new column.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (!Row.mydate_IsNull)
    {
        var paddedDate = Row.mydate.PadLeft(6, '0');
        var day = paddedDate.Substring(0, 2);
        var month = paddedDate.Substring(2, 2);
        var year = paddedDate.Substring(4, 2);
        Row.formattedDate = $"{day}-{month}-{year}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(DT_WSTR, 2)(DT_I4)LEFT(RIGHT("0"  +  @[User::date], 6), 2)
 + "-" +  SUBSTRING(RIGHT("0"  +  @[User::date], 6), 3, 2)
 + "-" + RIGHT(@[User::date] , 2)